# Tableau creating calculating column for whole table

Tags: mysql, tableau-api

Is tableau has a opportunity to create calculated column for table? For example here are 2 column with some number and I want to make third column with formula like this
`If(column1>column2;column1;column2`. I see there is option to create calculated field with summarize columns but I just want to compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to create a new column storing the max between 2 original column, you just need to create a calcultaed field like the following:

```
if column1 > column2
then column1
else column2
end
```

EDIT
Or even simpler

```
MAX([column1], [column2])
```

There are two (overloaded) functions named MAX(). With one argument, MAX() is an aggregate function that operates on a column of values and returns the maximum - just like other aggregate functions like SUM(), AVG() etc. With two arguments, MAX() is a record level function that operates on an individual data row and returns the larger of its two arguments. MIN() behaves similarly.

Comment: That is gonna help me but maybe you know how to refer to previous value? Function PREVIOUS_VALUE or LOOKUP needs to data be aggregate

Comment: you're right about the aggregation part but note that if you put the maximun level of grnularity in your worksheet, the sum of a the most granular level is equal to its value.

Comment: Yeah but it could work with string not number? I

Comment: could you provide more context?

Comment: I am looking for sth like this https://imgur.com/a/M1QGJ6b

Comment: @FabioFantoni there is an even simpler shortcut using max() - I edited your answer to describe. That simple trick is not as well known as it should be.

Comment: @Alex Blakemore you're absolutely right, sir... max and min are meant for that; the only reason I used that if statement is due to the generic topic about calculating a new column which sounded to me more entry level... the if statement is something you're gonna use a lot, so that's why... tbs: thanks a lot for the improvement!